# How to input a matrix in C language while not knowing the lengths of columns?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

I'm working on my **C-programming** homework, in which I need to create and output seven tables **with arrays**, and the rules for numbers in the seven tables are as follows:

> Table 1: start from 1, show 1 number, skip 1 number, repeat until 100
> Table 2: start from 2, show 2 numbers, skip 2 numbers, repeat until 100
> Table 3: start from 4, show 4 numbers, skip 4 numbers, repeat until 100
> Table 4: start from 8, show 8 numbers, skip 8 numbers, repeat until 100
> Table 5: start from 16, show 16 numbers, skip 16 numbers, repeat until 100
> Table 6: start from 32, show 32 numbers, skip 32 numbers, repeat until 100
> Table 7: start from 64, show every number until 100

My idea is that I could create a large table-- which I can put all the elements inside, with separate rows(tables) and columns(numbers in tables).

But here's a problem:
Assuming that **the only things we know are the rules of numbers and the number of tables,** what can we do to create a table without knowing the numbers of elements?

---

Now I've gotten the elements of each table-- but I'm now stuck in this step: how do I insert the elements into the table which has seven rows and unknown columns?

How I got the elements:

```
......
  //table1~6
  for(int table_number=1;table_number<=6;table_number++) {
    printf("table%d\n",table_number);
    for(int number=pow(2,table_number-1);number<=100;number+=pow(2,table_number)) {
      printf("%3d\n",number);
      for(int skip=1;skip<pow(2,table_number-1);skip++) {
        if(number+skip>100)break;
        else printf("%3d\n",number+skip);
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  //table7
  printf("table7\n");
  for(int number=pow(2,7-1);number<=100;number++){
    printf("%3d\n",number);
  }
```

Then how do I insert the elements into the table in the same way?

Comment: Rather than `//table1~6 for(int 
 table_number=1; table_number<=6; table_number++) {`, create a helper function  `int table1_6(int print)`.  Pass in a variable that controls if it actually prints or not. Return the count of numbers that would normally be printed.  Now you can call `table1_6(0)` to find the number of columns before actually printing and use that info how you like.

Comment: There are two common ways to end a loop, by knowing the number, or by knowing a condition. Perhaps there is some number that cannot be int the table, like 0, or -1, or 9999 - then use that number as an end signal and stop reading when it appears.

Answer (score 1):

> My idea is that I could create a large table-- which I can put all the elements inside, with separate rows(tables) and columns(numbers in tables).

Yes, you can do that. It's probably the easiest way to accomplish the task, if you *need* to use arrays.

> But here's a problem: Assuming that **the only things we know are the rules of numbers and the number of tables**, what can we do to create a table without knowing the numbers of elements?

Those data are actually enough to estimate the maximum capacity needed to store all the numbers.

Consider the first "table", it contains only the odd numbers below 100 and there are 50 of them.

The second "table" likewise contains half the values in the range.

The others are shorter, so that you could calculate the exact lengths and allocate the right amount of memory or just use arrays of the same size as the previous ones and keep track of actual sizes.

Again, the easiest way is probably to initialize all the values to zero (a value that is not supposed to be present) and then fill the arrays with the correct values until those are not greater than 100. When printing, just stop the loop when the maximum size is reached or a 0 is encountered.

See the following [example](https://godbolt.org/z/54qnhMn3b), to get an idea of how to implement it on your own.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  enum {
    N_TABLES = 7,
    MAX_VALUE = 100,
    MAX_SIZE = MAX_VALUE / 2   // <-- As noted, we don't need more then that.
  };
  // I'm using a multidimensional array to store all the "tables".
  int table[N_TABLES][MAX_SIZE] = {0};
  //                              ^^^  All the values are set to zero.

  for ( int t = 0; t < N_TABLES; ++t )
  {
    // Using pow (which returns a double) to calculate an integer power of two
    // might be inaccurate and maybe slower.
    unsigned start = 1u << t;

    // Well, don't use this "algorithm" in your assignment. It's unlikely what they
    // want you to do. Just note the use of the array.
    for ( unsigned number = start, i = 0; number <= MAX_VALUE; ++number )
    { //                           ^^^^^ 
      if ( number & start )
      {
        table[t][i] = number;
        ++i;                   // <- The index is incremented only when a new value
                               //    is assigned.
      }
    }
  }
  
  // I'll print the values in a tabular fashion. Just transposed.
  for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; ++i )
  {
    for ( int j = 0; j < N_TABLES; ++j )
    {
      if ( table[j][i] != 0 )
        printf("%5d", table[j][i]);
      else
        printf("     ");
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }
}
```